# Mongoose delete data from db after certain time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After exactly 1 hour, I need to delete the items in the array under the cart.

I did some research, but what I tried didn't work for me.

```js
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    validate: [isEmail, 'Geçersiz mail adresi!'],
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  resetToken: String,
  resetTokenExpiration: Date,
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  cart: {
    items: [{
      productId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product',
        required: true
      },
      quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update some part of data which has to be automatic. I'm sure you won't be deleting the user details, only want to update the `cart` data with `[]` or `null`.

For such purposes, you can use the cron-jobs on node.js which will trigger every hour, but it will remove all the documents at a specified time which might cause an unexpected behaviour for user who just added things in cart `1 minute` before the cron job runs.

However, you can make a query to check if that particular cart is expired or not and that can be run using cron-jobs, but I believe for that you need to parse every document which might increase the complexity and unnecessary burden on db.

So, I would like to suggest you to create another collection which holds the user cart information and add 'ttl' to the collection for a key `createdAt` (name whatever you like), this is being provided by `Mongodb` that will remove the document after the specific time lapsed for that particular document.

Creating index for cart specific collection

```
db.collectionName.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

While inserting the documents:

```
db.log_events.insert( {
   "createdAt": new Date(),
   "logEvent": 2,
   "logMessage": "Success!"
} )
```

To understand it thoroughly, I suggest you read [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/).

Comment: Thanks, you can also upvote it if that works.

Comment: I find it better to use expireAfterSeconds = 0, and then have a field 'expiredAt' which is set into the future (by in your case 3600), which you can update with a pre-save hook each time the document is changed. That way you don't have to re-build the index if say you decide to change the value 3600, to something else. Obviously, create the index on the updatedAt field in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of other options, but you can use something like [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule), to run at certain interval and clean the cart array.

For this to work you need to have an extra field in DB, which signifies the expiry time i.e. (cart creation time + 1 hr). This node-schedule function will check for the expiry time in the field value, if that value is greater than the current time then it will delete, else it will leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try [agenda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda)

Maintaining a separate collection for carts would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
    email: {
        type: String,
        validate: [isEmail, 'Geçersiz mail adresi!'],
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      resetToken: String,
      resetTokenExpiration: Date,
      isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      cart: {
        items: [{
          productId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Product',
            required: true
          },
          quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
          }
        }]
      },
      expiresAt: { type: Date, default: () => new Date(Date.now()+60*60*1000), },
});
```